Django: Upload File to Firebase and Save File Metadata to Sqlite3
I have a Django app, I am trying to upload the document to firebase. It uploads properly but the metadata does not upload to my sqlite3 database.
def uploadProject(request):
  print("INSIDE UPLOAD VIEW") #Prints
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print("INSIDE POST REQUEST") #Does not print
    form = UploadProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        file = request.FILES['file']
        file_url = upload_to_firebase(file)
        metadata = form.save(commit=False)
        metadata.file_url = file_url  model
        metadata.save()
        return redirect('upload-project')  
else:
    form = UploadProjectForm()
return render(request, 'base/upload_project.html', {'form': form})

This is my upload.js file that handles the form submission
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-storage.js";
import { storage } from "./firebase-config.js";

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
if (fileInput.files.length === 0) {
    alert('No file selected.');
    return;
}

const file = fileInput.files[0];
const storageRef = ref(storage, `uploads/${file.name}`);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
    (snapshot) => {
        // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    }, 
    (error) => {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        console.error('Upload failed:', error);
    }, 
    async () => {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    }
); });

This is my forms.py
class UploadProjectForm(ModelForm):
file = forms.FileField(required=True)  

class Meta:
    model = Document_Metadata
    fields = ['name', 'uploader_id', 'course_id', 'description', 'status']

